# mysql redirect to error page, NodeJS with Express framework

Tags: node.js, express, node-mysql

I have a NodeJS application with Express as framework.
In my app.js file I'm checking my connection to mysql database as below:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '',
  database : 'nodejs'
});

var routes = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);

// catch Database connection errors and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    connection.connect(function(err){
        if(err){
            var err = new Error('Database connection error! Try later please.');
            err.status = 503;
            next(err);    
        }
    });
});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

The part of the code that I'm expecting to work is this :

```
// catch Database connection errors and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    connection.connect(function(err){
        if(err){
            var err = new Error('Database connection error! Try later please.');
            err.status = 503;
            next(err);    
        }
    });
});
```

routes/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index');
});

module.exports = router;
```

When I run my server with a wrong password, nothing happenes the page is served, here is my log:

```
GET / 304 17.940 ms - -
GET /vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css 304 2.915 ms - -
```

Any help how to display an error page when a DB error (connection or bad query) occures?

Thanks

Thanks

Comment: because i think, your code never reaches to database errors. Share the logic of route '/ .'

Comment: I don't think what you pointed is the reason, why the 404 page is fired when a routeis missing? so that part of code about DB I think is reached.

Comment: there is no `404` error, it is `304` which means it loaded properly.

Comment: Do you understand my issue? I want to display a view saying error in database connection when there is an error. right now I don't see my code working.

Comment: I don't want to print in console, I want to show a veiw saying Site is down or something so that users can know that.

Answer (score 1):

This is really poor, why would you to want to call the `middleware` every time to check for `connection` for each `request`?

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    connection.connect(function(err){
        if(err){
            var err = new Error('Database connection error! Try later please.');
            err.status = 503;
            next(err);    
        }
    });
});
```

Instead you can use to log errors when ever something wrong happens with your code. This will `catch` all `errors`.

```
router.use(function (err, req, res, next) {  
    /* log the error internaly */
    logger.error(err);
    res.status(err.statusCode || 500).json(err);
});
```

Below are some link which you can help you further:

1. http://expressjs.com/en/guide/database-integration.html
2. http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

On the error for 304, try this in your dev console and see if it works:
[Disabling Chrome cache for website development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development)

**Update:**

Your db connection: `db.js`

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '',
    database : 'nodejs'
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
    console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
    return;
}});

module.exports = connection;
```

Now your `index.js`

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    db = require('./db');

app.get('/',function(req,res){
    var query = db.query('Select * from your table', function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    });
});

server.listen(3000);
```

Now when the `error` happens, you get the `error` `message` and `code`, with that in your `middleware` you can throw them to a view in `public/databaseError.html`

Comment: Sounds like no one is understanding my question. I would like in NodeJs + express + mysql-node to check if the database is working because all my site relies on DB queries so that if the DB is not working I want to render only one view saying DB error, all the rest views should not render